# I wish to make more complex possible-responses for my program

Tags: java

Now, let's say I wanted to make a more diverse array of usable responses from the user_input;

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class playerinput {

    private static Scanner user_input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

        String firstName;
        System.out.print("Enter your name here:");
        firstName = user_input.next();

        String lastName;
        System.out.print("Ok cool, and your last?:");
        lastName = user_input.next();

        String thankYou;

        thankYou = "Alright," + ' ' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ',' + ' '
         + "that's all we'll need. Have a nice day, and thank you again.";      

        System.out.println(thankYou);   

        System.out.println("Oh, one more question, if you don't mind.");
        String Response = user_input.next();
        if (user_input.equals("Yea?")&("Yes?"))


        if (){

        }
    }
}
```

Here I simply want to make the userinput responses Yea? and Yes?
the only responses it can accept to initiate the next system.out.println,
and if you say anything else like No for instance, it'll simply 
system.out.println("Fine, thank you for your time)"
then break;

As you can see, im pretty well confused

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use an OR operator instead ( `||` ) like so: `if(user_input.equals("Yes?") || user_input.equals("Yea?") ){ //code here }`  You can find more information in this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to edit the if clause to work properly, and add an "else" clause to cover every other case. Also, you don't need a `break;` at the end since you're not actually breaking out of anything.

```
if (user_input.equals("Yea?") || user_input.equals("Yes?")) {
    //Do something like printing
    System.out.println("Do you also like pineapples?");
} else {
    //All other user inputs are taken into account here
    //Do your printing
    System.out.println("Fine, thank you for your time");
}
```